# Join tables and fetch the data to a table using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have two db tables named as `verification_details` and `verification_questions`.  `verification_id` is common in two tables.  In `verification_details` table, there is a `user_id` field, based on this `user_id` field, one or more verification details inserted into the `verification_details` table and based on the `verification_id` one or more verification questions inserted into the `verification_questions` table.
I use this code in model for join query

```
function get_records() {

    $this->db->select("a.criteria_question,a.criteria_answer,a.validation_statement");
        $this->db->from("verification_questions as a");
        $this->db->join('verification_details as b', 'a.verification_id = b.verification_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();    
}
```

I want the controller code for fetching all datas from both tables and display it in a table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Model

```
function get_records() {

    $this->db->select("a.criteria_question,a.criteria_answer,a.validation_statement");
    $this->db->from("verification_questions as a");
    $this->db->join('verification_details as b', 'a.verification_id = b.verification_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

In contoller

```
$data['table'] = $this->Model_name->get_records();
$this->load->view('view_name',$data);
```

and in view

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Question</th>
        <th>Answer</th>
        <th>Validation</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach ( $table as $new_item )
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $new_item['table field1']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $new_item['table field2']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $new_item['table field3']?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }

    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create array of result in model and use it in controller.

**Model:**

```
function get_records()
{
        $this->db->select("a.criteria_question,a.criteria_answer,a.validation_statement");
        $this->db->from("verification_questions as a");
        $this->db->join('verification_details as b', 'a.verification_id = b.verification_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $select = array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $select[] = $row;
        }
        if (count($select) > 0)
            return $select;
        return NULL;
}
```

You can use this function in controller to get result array.

**Controller:**

```
$data['result']=$this->modelname->get_records();
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

And, finally you have to pass result variable to view to display in table.

**View:**

```
<table><tr><td>Question></td></tr>
    if(count($result)>0){
        foreach($result as $row){ ?>
            <tr><td><?= $row->criteria_question; ?></td></tr>
        <?php}
    } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code is almost right. But you make it little lengthy i mean no need of using foreach loop two times you can achieve it using single time also !!! But i appreciate your guidance !!